# Footer Slide Up Transition Jquery or CSS3

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to recreate this cool slide up footer that i found on [The Internship Movie Site](http://www.theinternshipmovie.com/). Now I've done the wireframe layout, but I'm having trouble guessing the correct CSS transition effect. I've tried using the "top" and "height" transition properties but I can't seem to get it. My guess it's just something very minor that I'm missing, or perhaps I should just use Jquery instead of CSS. Let me know what you guys think and here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8sv2/)

**HTML**

```
<!-- Begin Site Wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">

<!-- Begin Header -->
<div id="header">Menu List Here
    </div><!-- End Header -->

<!-- Begin Site Content -->
<div id="sitecontent">Some Site Content Goes Here
    </div><!-- End Site Content -->    

<!-- Begin Footer --> 
    <div id="footerwrapper">
        <div id="footerleft">Left</div>
        <div id="footercenter">Center</div>
        <div id="footerright">Right</div>
        <div id="hugetextreveal">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</div>
    </div> <!-- End Footerwrapper -->
</div> <!-- End Site Wrapper -->
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;}
#header {background: #000; color: #fff; height: 30px; text-align: center}
#sitecontent {min-height: 400px; background: #ff0000;}

#footerwrapper {width: 600px; height: 40px; background: #000; color: #fff; text-align: center; position: relative; overflow: hidden}
#footerleft {width: 200px; float: left; position: relative }
#footercenter {width: 200px;  float: left; position: relative }
#footerright {width: 200px;  float: left; position: relative }
#hugetextreveal {width: 100%; height: auto;  float: left; padding-top: 20px; position: relative;  transition: max-height 0.7s ease-in;  }

#footerwrapper:hover #hugetextreveal {
max-height: 200px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added changes to these two lanes, have a look, it's really simple

```
#footerwrapper {width: 600px; height: 40px; bottom:0px;  background: #000; color: #fff; text-align: center; position: relative; overflow: hidden; transition: all 0.5s ease 0.2s; }
#footerwrapper:hover { height:140px; bottom:100px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e8sv2/7/

Comment: I was soooo close!! It was bottom that was one of the keys to making this work :). Thanks again!

Comment: this isn't cross-browser compatible.

Comment: @DrCord basically the answer is supposed to guide the way, not do the work for the poster, however transitions were introduced in 2010 if I'm not mistaking. Any browser that doesn't support technology from 3 years ago deserves to be incompatible. That's just my ideology, makes the designer's life a whole lot easier `:D`

Comment: you did more work for him, left less for him to figure out and gave a less compatible browser wise answer than me...

Comment: @DrCord Your answer is completely irrelevant to the actual code that the poster has provided along with the question, all you have done is copy some styling from a website, which is apparently inapplicable to the OP's scenario, which you would have known if you tried to actually dig into the problem. On a side note all recent versions of the prefixes used in your answer recognize a transition property without the prefix.

Comment: @php_nub_qq - I read and grocked their entire question, however the core question was that they could not figure out what the transition effect was the site used. Like you said above the point isn't to code their site for them it is to help them. They clearly state that they are jsut trying to figure out how the transistion is accomplished and whether it is jQuery.

Comment: @DrCord They said they are having a baffle deciding which way to go, not just wondering how this particular site does it. If all they wanted to know was how the site is doing it why would they include their code and also construct a demo? All I've done is add a few properties to two selectors, you call that "coding their site for them" ?

Comment: You gave them the answer instead of allowing them to think for themselves, which you chided me for above, to quote you "basically the answer is supposed to guide the way, not do the work for the poster".

Answer (score 1):

The page in question you would like to copy, It's all CSS transistions:

```
#footer:hover {
    height: 295px;
}
#footer{
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: height 0.5s ease;
    transition: height 0.5s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do this in jQuery:

```
$("#footerwrapper").hover(function () {
    $("#hugetextreveal").fadeIn(700);
},
function () {
    $("#hugetextreveal").fadeOut(700);
});
```

Comment: Looks like you might need slideUp and slideDown, or animate() instead of fades.